# Returning reference to an array of specific size without explicitly stating the size in return type

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, return-type

I've got the following function:

```
... getX()
{
    static int x[] = {1, 2, 3};
    return x;
}
```

I'd like to have its return type as `int(&)[3]` but don't wan't to specify the size (3) explicitly.

How do I do that?

(Please don't ask *why* I want that.)

**UPD**

Well, OK, I need to pass a result to a template function taking `int(&x)[N]` as a parameter (and I don't want to pass the size explicitly to that template function), so I don't see how a solution with returning a pair could work...

Comment: `int *` .......

Comment: How about `std::pair<int*, size_type>`  where `size_type` is the number of elements?

Comment: Do the same thing as people do for strings as char* - add a (null) terminator.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In C++14:

```
auto& getX()
{
    static int x[] = {1, 2, 3};
    return x;
}
```

Also, consider using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of C-style arrays.

---

I cannot currently think of any Standard-compliant C++11 solution. Here's one using *compound literals*, assuming that your goal is to not repeat the elements and to deduce a reference-to-array:

```
#include <type_traits>

#define ITEMS 1, 2, 3
auto getX() -> decltype((int[]){ITEMS})
{
    static int x[] = {ITEMS};
    return x;
}
#undef ITEMS

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(getX()), int(&)[3]>{});
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do something similar for C++11? I have to do it for both versions, sorry, I forgot to mention. I've got reasons to use C-style arrays, API with templates and array ref parameters..

Comment: @ledonter: added a C++11 solution/hack

Comment: @VittorioRomeo as compound-literals are an extension, I think making it explicit that they're can avoid confusion.

Comment: You can avoid compound literals by aliasing `int[]` like this: `using int_array = int[]; auto getX() -> decltype(int_array{ITEMS}) & {...}`

Answer (score 3):

Do you *need* the size available as a compile-time constant? I would suggest using `gsl::span` (or roll your own). This is basically just a pointer and a size, that satisfies the range concept:

```
gsl::span<int> getX()
{
    static int x[] = {1, 2, 3};
    return x;
}
```

Comment: It isn't part of the standard library. Am I wrong? Probably you should mention it otherwise.

Comment: Except the OP intends to pass the result into a template function that expects an array reference parameter.

Answer (score 2):

#### C++11

Another C++11 alternative (workaround), in case your theoretical scenario (not asking why ...) allows wrapping the `static` array as a (literal) static data member of an otherwise stateless type:

```
class Foo
{
    static constexpr int x[] = {1, 2, 3};
    // delete ctor(s) ...
public:
    static auto getX() -> std::add_lvalue_reference<decltype(x)>::type { return x; }
};
constexpr int Foo::x[];
```

Or, e.g.

```
class Foo
{
    template <typename T, std::size_t n>
    static constexpr std::size_t array_size(const T (&)[n]) { return n; }

    static constexpr int x[] = {1, 2, 3};

    // delete ctor(s) ...
public:
    template<std::size_t N = array_size(x)>
    static const int (&getX())[N] { return x; }
};
constexpr int Foo::x[];
```

Any of the two above applied in the use case you describe in your question:

```
template <std::size_t N>
void feedX(const int (&x)[N])
{
    for (const auto num: x) { std::cout << num << "\n"; }    
} 

int main()
{
    feedX(Foo::getX()); /* 1
                           2
                           3 */
}
```

This wouldn't help you in case your theoretical scenario would need to mutate the static data, though. You could tweak the above into a mutating-allowing scenario, but at the cost of having to specify the size of `x` at its declaration, as it can no longer be (constant-)initialized and size-deduced at that point, and I believe this size explicitness is what you wanted to avoid in the first place. Anyway, for completeness:

```
class Foo
{
    static int x[3];
public:
    static auto getX() -> std::add_lvalue_reference<decltype(x)>::type { return x; }
};
int Foo::x[] = {1, 2, 3};

template <std::size_t N>
void feedAndMutateX(int (&x)[N])
{
    for (auto& num: x) { std::cout << num++ << "\n"; }    
} 

int main()
{
    feedAndMutateX(Foo::getX()); /* 1
                                    2
                                    3 */
    feedAndMutateX(Foo::getX()); /* 2
                                    3
                                    4 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a reference, and have C++14, then `decltype(auto)` with a parenthesized id expression:

```
decltype(auto) get_arr() {
    static int x[] = {1, 2 ,3};

    return (x);
}
```

Will deduce as a reference to the array of *that* size. [See it live](https://ideone.com/qnD7nE), where the type of the reference is shown in the error message.

Comment: If you really want a reference, use `auto&`... that's a reference.